# How many Software Serial can use with arduino nano, uno and leonardo?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, wifi, esp8266

I am trying to use multiple serial ports with this arduino models.

I am planning to use 1 ESP8266 module and 1 Hm-10 BLE module.

I want to connect webserver via ESP. But I have to send my ssid and wifi password to esp.

For this situation I planned write  a android application that  sends ssid and pass to our arduino and esp module.

Is it possible?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research about this and I only found two answers at the moment:

1. **Native Arduino's Serial Ports + 1:** Using the library SoftwareSerial (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) to add a "second" serial to listen. So you can use common Arduino's serial ports and other custom defined digital pins (2 pins) to simulate a native Arduino's serial port. An example using BT with ESP8266 can be found here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Dual-Controlled-RC-Car-Bluetooth-and-WiFi/step2/The-Connection/
2. **As many devices as suported by your hardware configuration/specifications:** Using the same serial port to control several devices with the same baud rates and then you must choose which one you want to listen at a time. With some code you can wait for a variable to be setted (with BLE) and when it's done change to listen just the other (ESP8266).

There is an example combining this two answers that may help you looking for the example "Two Port Receive" in the link I provided before about SoftwareSerial library.